# differentiating bot and users and insert real human ip to database

Tags: php, apache, user-agent, bots

i am  tracking the users at my site through php and mysql but the bot is creating problem .more than users bot are available at my site and i want to enter only real users ip address not bot ip address. i know few ip address of google which starts from 66.249  like that ip address from bing also start from somthing like that.but for several other search engine bot like yandex baidu and others i cant predict the ip address. i have thought of using if else statment to do so. for example if

```
  $ip=='66.249'

  {do nothing}


     else {
   insert into database

    }
```

but i am thinking if there is something which can identify bot easily and i can use something like that

```
if  

 useragent=='bot'

     {
     do nothing 
        } 

      else 

       {
      insert into database
        }
```

please suggest anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check for `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'`] in php . Humans will be having values like Mozilla etc.

Comment: how to differentiate with bot.

Comment: for example google will be having values like Googlebot/1.0 , MSN will be having Msnbot like that

Comment: i agree but i want to differentiate all bot vs human .otherwise i can do the same with specifying google bot ip address but in that case i should know all available bot so i am preferring this. or i can do something like this if $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']=%bot% {do nothing} but i have worry with this it will slow down process and create load on server??  i dont think it will create load on server as php will do it very fast please advise

Comment: U have to check the result of $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']  whether it matches patterns like Mozilla ,Konqueror etc . You can have list of vaild user agents from a simple search in google

Comment: i think my way is better . i will check for word bot if it mathches just ignore else insert into database

Comment: But some bots like Ask Jeeves does not have a word bot attached to them. Anyway you can give a try.

Comment: surprized to see that google bot useragent is not consisting of any bot word. difficult to differentiate   66.249.85.157Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko; Google Web Preview) Chrome/27.0.1453 Safari/537.36-9ya